# Interaction with dynamically created elements using Vanilla JavaScript . I cant get any interaction to a element Created

Tags: javascript

1. I create the elements in HTML variable,  using a btn click , then it is appended to a div. After that , i cant get any interaction with the elements cretated.  I really want to do it without Jquery.

   ```
    btnAdd.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input.value === "") {
        alert("Insert.text")
    } else {
        store.push(input.value);
        counter += 1
        let createDivList = document.createElement("div");
        createDivList.classList.add("list")
        const Html =
            `<div class="text">
                    <h5>${input.value}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="icons">
                    <span class="btn-done icon"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i></i></span>
                    <span class="btn-editar icon"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></span>
                    <span class="btn-recliclar icon"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
                </div>
                `;
        createDivList.innerHTML = Html;
        todoList.appendChild(createDivList)
        input.value = "";
    }
   ```

   })

   ```
    remove.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            alert("hello")
        })
    });
   ```

Comment: You need to add event listeners to the buttons you inserted, *after* inserting them.

Comment: I declared it Before the "btnAdd.addEventListener" , declaring it after , doesnt seem to take any affect

Comment: That's because you need to add the listeners *inside* the `(e) => { ... }` callback, right after your `todoList.appendChild(createDivList)` What you tried didn't work because when the code ran, there is no element with a `.btn-done` class yet.

Comment: Something like this wont work :
 
        createDivList.innerHTML = Html;
        todoList.appendChild(createDivList)
        input.value = "";
        const remove = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-recliclar");

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you getting error messages? Also, that code doesn't really *do* anything, except for clearing whatever `input` is. It doesn't actually use `remove` for instance.